# How to sort Array containing that contains NSDictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, ios6, nssortdescriptor

Suppose I would like to sort array by "firstName" key.

Example

```
Array = (
   {
     People1 = {
         firstName = @"Jack Adam";
         email = @"adam@gmail.com";
     };
     Address = {
         cityCode = @"TH";
     };
   },
     People2 = {
         firstName = @"Jack DAm";
         email = @"dam@gmail.com";
     };
      Address = {
         city = @"TH";
     };
);
```

Comment: Is it really "People1" in the first dictionary and "People2" in the second? Why do you use different keys for each array element?

Comment: @MartinR  It's my wrong. It should be "People1" and "People1".

Answer (score 2):

user Sort Comparator

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSDictionary *a, NSDictionary *b) {

  return [a[@"People"][@"firstname"] compare:b[@"People"][@"firstname"]];

}];
```

But Your Key is inconsistency ... 
I Think that data should be

```
Array = (
{
 People = {
     firstName = @"Jack Adam";
     email = @"adam@gmail.com";
 };
 Address = {
     cityCode = @"TH";
 };
},
 People = {
     firstName = @"Jack DAm";
     email = @"dam@gmail.com";
 };
  Address = {
     city = @"TH";
 };
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First,you should implement a compare-method for your object.

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(Person *)otherObject {
    return [self.birthDate compare:otherObject.birthDate];
}

NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [drinkDetails sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using blocks and modern Objective-C syntax:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSDictionary *first, NSDictionary *second) {

      return [first[@"Person"] compare:second[@"Person"]];

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using NSSortDescriptor:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName"  ascending:YES];
    myArray=[stories sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
    temp = [stories copy]; //temp is NSMutableArray
```

myArray is the array you want to sort.

Answer (score 0):

As you replied in a comment, the first dictionary key is "Person1" in all array elements.
Then "Person1.firstName" is the ***key path*** that gives the first name of each array
element. This key path can be used in a sort descriptor:

```
NSArray *array = ... // your array
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Person1.firstName" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
```